# MKMapView prevent annotations grouping

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I have a `MKMapView` with several annotations and 3 of them are very close to each other.

I used `mapView.showAnnotations(mapView.annotations, animated: false)` to display all annotations on the same region at launch but one of the 3 is hidden because it's too close.

I looked into Apple's Documentation but couldn't find a way to prevent this from happening, any idea how to prevent annotations grouping?

(I've never seen this before, maybe it's a iOS 11 feature)

Comment: your annotations by default don't have grouping behavior, but if are too close then one overlaps the other

Comment: @ReinierMelian Yup I saw that. Is there a way to show every annotations even if they overlap each other like on Google Maps?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are seeing ist not clustering (you had to write code to get a cluster and you would usually see a cluster)

My experiments appear to suggest...

1. `MKAnnotationViews` are rendered from top to bottom of the map. (It doesn't matter where north is).
2. If `MapKit` decides to draw overlapping `MKAnnotationViews`, then the `MKAnnotationView` nearer to the bottom is drawn on top (because it's drawn later)
3. Not only `MKAnnotationViews`, also titles rendered below `MKMArkerAnnotationViews` need space. The rendering of those titles is influenced by `markerView.titleVisibility`. If `markerView.titleVisibility` is set to `.visible` (instead of the default `.adaptive`), then this title is stronger than a `MarkerAnnotationView` that is rendered later, even if the later `MarkerAnnotationView` has a `displayPriority = .required`. The `MarkerAnnotationView` nearer to the bottom is not rendered.
4. This even happens if the `MarkerAnnotationView` nearer to the top has a low `displayPriority`. So a `MarkerAnnotationView` with low `displayPriority` and `.titleVisibility = .visible` can make a `MarkerAnnotationView` nearer to the bottom with `displayPriority = .required` disappear.

So what should you do:

1. make sure `annotationView.displayPriority = .required` for all relevant annotations. (This is necessary but not sufficient)
2. Do *not* set `annotationView.titleVisibility = .visible` or the title will make annotationViews disappear that are rendered nearer the bottom. Instead set `annotationView.titleVisibility = .adaptive`

I don't think you can control the visibility completely. But the problem with `annotationView.titleVisibility = .visible` was surprising for me and you should avoid it because it *will* hide annotations.

Clusters behave like (and are) annotations that behave exactly as described above, if clusters are used.

**Edit, a few years later:**

Since **iOS 14**, `MKAnnotationView` has two new variables:

- `zPriority` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkannotationview/3547913-zpriority
- `selectedZPriority` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkannotationview/3547912-selectedzpriority

Set a higher value to make sure the more important `MKAnnotationView` stays visible. This works nicely.

For Annotations with the same `zPriority`, the text above is still valid.

Please be aware that Apple decided to make `zPriority` a property of `MKAnnotationView` and not of `MKAnnotation`.

This means as soon as MapKit decides to hide your favourite `MKAnnotationView`, you can't set the `zPriority` variable any more since the view doesn't exit any more. I solve this by setting `zPriority` immediately after creation of the `MKAnnotationView`. This last paragraph is not in Apples documentation.

Comment: I was skeptical but the combination of `.displayPriority = .required` and `.titleVisibility = .adaptive` solved this problem for me, too.