Is it possible to change the tint of the title/subtitle labels of a MKMarkerAnnotationView in iOS?
I'm working with an iOS app using a map full of MKMarkerAnnotationView objects. I'm dealing with the typical custom markers where you can customize the looks, change the glyph, the tint, etc... All this works ok.
The thing is my annotations have also title and subtitle attributes set, so they show in the map perfectly under the marker itself... But I've noticed that these 2 pieces of text always appear rendered in black with a nice thin white stroke surrounding the letters...
I've really searched for it but I haven't been able to find anything, so I ask it here:

Is it possible to change the tint of the title and the subtitle
labels rendition of a MKMarkerAnnotationView ?


Greetings

Reasoning from some effects, when Titles and Markers can hide each other, I believe that Apple handles Markers and Titles as two completely separate objects. that are placed independently on the map. That said, I don't think you'll find an undocumented direct relation that you can follow. If there is something reachable, it should be a separate layer of the map (that is not visible in the visual debugger).  The reason why I think this is the case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46180887/mkmapview-prevent-annotations-grouping/57457734#57457734
